# spring webflux CORS headers getting removed

Tags: java, spring-boot, cors, spring-webflux, reactive

**EDIT**: Please read the updates, the problem has been changed significantly.

I am very badly blocked on this. I have a spring webflux app and I am trying to enable CORS headers on it, so that I am able to do requests from different origins in the same browser sessions. But whatever I do, the CORS headers are getting removed(even if I put them manually in the ServerResponse). Some of the classes in security/ and config/ I am using are:

```
package com.document.feed.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableReactiveMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.EnableWebFluxSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;

import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

    @EnableWebFluxSecurity
    @EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig {

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Autowired
        private SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository;

        @Bean
        SecurityWebFilterChain springWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
            String[] patterns = new String[] {"/auth/**", "/vanillalist"};
            return http
                    .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint((swe, e) -> Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
                        swe.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
                    })).accessDeniedHandler((swe, e) -> Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
                        swe.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
                    })).and()
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                    .securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository)
                    .authorizeExchange()
                        .pathMatchers(patterns).permitAll()
                        .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
                    .anyExchange().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .build();
        }
    }
```

SecurityContextRepository.java

```
package com.document.feed.security;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ServerSecurityContextRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;

import com.document.feed.config.JwtTokenUtil;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Component
public class SecurityContextRepository implements ServerSecurityContextRepository {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityContextRepository.class);

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    @Override
    public Mono save(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, SecurityContext sc) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public Mono load(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange) {
        System.out.println("serverWebExchange:" + serverWebExchange.getAttributes());
        ServerHttpRequest request = serverWebExchange.getRequest();
        String authHeader = request.getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        String authToken = null;
        if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith(JwtTokenUtil.TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
            authToken = authHeader.replace(JwtTokenUtil.TOKEN_PREFIX, "");
        }else {
            logger.warn("couldn't find bearer string, will ignore the header.");
        }
        System.out.println("SecurityContextRepository.authToken=" + authToken +
                    "\nauthHeader=" + authHeader);
        String username;
        try {
            username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(authToken);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            username = null;
        }
        System.out.println("SecurityContextRepository.username:" + username);
        if (authToken != null) {
            Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authToken, authToken);
            return authenticationManager.authenticate(auth).map((authentication) -> {
                SecurityContextHolder
                        .getContext().setAuthentication((Authentication) authentication);
                return new SecurityContextImpl((Authentication) authentication);
            });
        } else {
            return Mono.empty();
        }
    }

}

package com.document.feed.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.config.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.config.EnableWebFlux;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.config.WebFluxConfigurer;

import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SecurityConfiguration;

@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
@Import({CorsConfiguration.class, SecurityConfiguration.class})
public class CorsGlobalConfiguration implements WebFluxConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry corsRegistry) {
        corsRegistry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
                .allowCredentials(false)
                .exposedHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                        "Access-Control-Max-Age",
                        "Access-Control-Request-Headers",
                        "Access-Control-Request-Method");
    }
}
```

See, how headers `Access-Control-Allow-*` are dropped, while `Access-Control-Request-*` are retained in response headers.
[image]

The error seen in chrome's console:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/vanillalist', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
  }
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(console.log)
Promise {<pending>}
2VM778:1 OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/vanillalist 404 (Not Found)
(anonymous) @ VM778:1
:3000/#/:1 Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/vanillalist' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
:3000/#/:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

**Update:** Image for the 3rd comment.[image: 3rd comment]

**Update2:** `curl -v` requested by @mikeb, after adding `OPTIONS` in request headers.

```
(venv) NB292:scaligent devansh.dalal$ curl -v http://localhost:8080/vanillalist > /tmp/r.txt
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /vanillalist HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< transfer-encoding: chunked
< Vary: Origin
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
< Content-Type: application/json
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< X-XSS-Protection: 1 ; mode=block
< Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
< 
{ [8 bytes data]
100 1350k    0 1350k    0     0  19.9M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 19.9M
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

**Update3**: The problem has been reduced now to handle the `OPTIONS` kind of requests.

Comment: so when I added a route for `OPTIONS` and started returning `ServerResponse.ok()` for it, `fetch` started working for me. but basically Is that the workaround. I go about adding a handler for `OPTIONS` REST call?

Answer (score 3):

Override addCorsMappings() is not effective after using Spring Security. Just define a `CorsConfigurationSource` bean will work for you. See the following code, it is written in kotlin,

```
@Configuration
class GlobalWebConfig {

    private fun corsConfiguration(corsProperties: CorsProperties): CorsConfiguration {
        val corsConfiguration = CorsConfiguration()
        corsConfiguration.allowCredentials = corsProperties.credentials
        corsConfiguration.allowedHeaders = corsProperties.headers
        corsConfiguration.allowedOrigins = corsProperties.origins
        corsConfiguration.allowedMethods = corsProperties.methods
        corsConfiguration.maxAge = corsProperties.age
        return corsConfiguration
    }

    @Bean
    fun corsConfigurationSource(corsProperties: CorsProperties): CorsConfigurationSource {
        val source = UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource()
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration(corsProperties))
        return source
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you can define a `CorsWebFilter` bean.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that fetch tries to do an OPTIONS request as a preflight, and you need to allow OPTIONS as well as GET, PUT, etc...

```
.allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
```

That should fix your issue.

See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests

> Unlike “simple requests” (discussed above), "preflighted" requests first send an HTTP request by the OPTIONS method to the resource on the other domain, to determine if the actual request is safe to send. Cross-site requests are preflighted like this since they may have implications to user data.

The easiest way to support OPTIONS for all requests is via a filter. Write a filter that will detect and OPTIONS request and respond to it.

Comment: Test your request with `curl -v` and see what you get with a GET request.  Then test with OPTIONS instead of GET and see what headers you get.

Comment: Please see 3rd comment, I am getting `Vary: Origin` `Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method`, `Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers` are there extra in `curl -v`

Comment: Again, test your request with `curl -v` so you can see exactly what is happening. The browser screen shots are not terribly helpful for me.

Comment: Updated the question with what you requested. @mikeb

Comment: Seems like my spring server is not returning ok status for OPTIONS pre-flight, thats why I am getting CORS error. Wondering, if I need to write a handler for OPTIONS call also? @SecretAgentMan.

Comment: I typically use a filter to respond to OPTIONS requests so I don't have to add every endpoint that I have in my app. Create a request filter that sees an OPTIONS request and responds appropriately